# If $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$, then $f$ is not one-to-one.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I tried to use the contour line and the problem is equivalent to show that the contour line of the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is not a single point. I also thought about the Mean Value Theorem (MVT).

If for each $a\in\mathbb{R}^2$, we have to $\text{grad }f(a)\neq0$, so we can to define $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, by $$g(\theta)=f(a+v)-f(a)= \langle\text{grad }f(a+\theta v),v\rangle,$$ $v\in\mathbb{R}^2.$ Where $\theta$ comes from the MVT. So, I would like to use the Intermediate Value Theorem, to show that there is $c\in(0,1)$ such that $g(c)=0$. Then $f$ can not be one-to-one.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the gradient vanishes everywhere, then $f$ is constant, hence not one-to-one. Otherwise, pick a point $a$ such that $\nabla f(a) \neq 0$ and use the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) to deduce the level set of $f$ through $a$ is a curve.
2. Your desired conclusion actually holds for *continuous* $f$. If $f$ is constant there's nothing to prove. Otherwise, pick points $a$ and $b$ such that $f(a) \neq f(b)$. Now join $a$ to $b$ by a continuous path $\gamma$; by the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), the function $f\circ \gamma$ achieves every real value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, i.e., $f$ itself achieves every such value on the image of $\gamma$. To complete the proof, join $a$ to $b$ by two paths whose images touch only at $a$ and $b$ (e.g., a line segment and a semicircle).